# UIButton insets bug for multiline attributed title

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift-playground

I want to design a button respecting these rules:

- Content horizontally centered
- 18px margin on both side of the content
- 10px between image and title
- Title will wrap on multiple line if needed
- Use attributed title

I have a working solution using:

```
button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
```

Result:

[image: result obtained using setTitle]

But I can't figure why it's not working if I use:

```
button.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: title), for: .normal)
```

Result:

[image: result obtained using setAttributedTitle]

It does not respect the 10px and 18px insets. Also note that the problem only occurs when the title becomes multiline.

Here is the playground I used to pinpoint my problem:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}

class ActionBarView: UIView {
    // MARK: Properties

    private var icon: UIImage?

    private let stackView = UIStackView()
    private let proposeButton = UIButton()
    private let declineButton = UIButton()

    // MARK: Initialization

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        designView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: Design

    private func designView() {
        designIcon()

        designStackView()
        designProposeButton()
        designDeclineButton()
    }

    private func designIcon() {
        let image = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        image.backgroundColor = .magenta
        icon = UIImage.imageWithView(view: image)
    }

    private func designStackView() {
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(proposeButton)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(declineButton)
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 1

        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.frame = frame
    }

    private func designProposeButton() {
        design(button: proposeButton,
               icon: icon,
               title: "Propose   a task")
    }

    private func designDeclineButton() {
        design(button: declineButton,
               icon: icon,
               title: "Decline")
    }

    private func design(button: UIButton, icon: UIImage?, title: String) {
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 18, bottom: 0, right: 18)
        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 10)

        button.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = .green
        button.imageView?.backgroundColor = .orange

        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.setImage(icon, for: .normal)
//        button.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: title), for: .normal)
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    }
}

let view = ActionBarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 44))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```